# Statistical analysis for interaction of genes in multisamples

Tags: r, paired-data

Say I have 120 human individuals. I have done gene-gene interaction in those individuals and found the frequency of all the interacting genes as shown in the data below. I want to do some analysis to tell if one pair of gene interacts more than by chance. What kind of test I need to do and is there a way to do this in R? In this data below '*' separates first interacting gene with second. I have 75 such interactions in this data (75 rows)

```
genes  frequency 
A*B        15
V*F        4
G*H        1
G*A        12
```

Comment: How do you define 'chance' for gene interaction?

Comment: @Tal I just want to say if some interactions are significant (statistically more frequent ?)

Comment: More frequent than what? How often do you expect to observe interactions under your null hypothesis?

Comment: @Tal I think this is exploratory data and can't have any null hypothesis. I think I should just present it in terms of percentage. I mean in x percentage of individuals.

Comment: Then there's no statistical testing, just estimation. You can think of each interaction percentage as a binomial proportion and provide a binomial confidence interval around that number. I'd suggest that you'll go over similar studies in your field to see whether there's an accepted way to define 'chance' (=null hypothesis) for these interactions.

Comment: @Tal Thanks. That is what I realized I should be doing. I know they have not done any statistical testing, but I can always compare against their data.